# When callback in useEffect hook fires?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I've read, that `useEffect` is asynchronous, so React firstly renders and mounts page and only after callback in useEffect fires, so sometimes we see value changing really fast in some components.

But when I tried to use self-created "sleep-for-3-seconds" in useEffect callback, React waits until 3 seconds pass, and only after that renders and mounts page, so I see blank page for 3 seconds. Also we can notice fast-changing value after 3 seconds delay. I don't get why it happens, as useEffect callback should be run after rendering and mounting the page.

Can you please explain why it happens in a such way?

***Code Sandbox:*** [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-flower-2rw1ik?file=/src/App.js)

Code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1200000000);
  useEffect(() => {
    let start = new Date().getTime();
    let end = start;
    while (end < start + 3000) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
    }
    setState(3);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div>Value is : {state}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: well your "busy wait" completely blocks the browser from doing anything for 3 seconds - including updating the DOM. While `useEffect` runs after React has rendered, I guess your example proves that the actual DOM hasn't been updated yet. Not sure it matters because (I hope!) you clearly would never put any synchronous, blocking code like this in a real app!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've read, that `useEffect` is asynchronous, so React firstly renders and mounts page and only after callback in `useEffect` fires, so sometimes we see value changing really fast in some components.

Correct. That's documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

> The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen.

and [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects)

> **Timing of effects**
>
> Unlike `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, the function passed to `useEffect` fires after **layout** and **paint**, during a deferred event.

*(their emphasis)*

Continuing with your question:

> But when I tried to use self-created "sleep-for-3-seconds" in useEffect callback, React waits until 3 seconds pass, and only after that renders and mounts page, so I see blank page for 3 seconds.

That's odd, I don't see that behavior:

```js
const { useState, useEffect} = React;

function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState(1200000000);
    useEffect(() => {
        let start = new Date().getTime();
        let end = start;
        while (end < start + 3000) {
            end = new Date().getTime();
        }
        setState(3);
    }, []);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <div>Value is : {state}</div>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

When I run that, I see the page rendered with the initial `1200000000` state value, then three seconds later I see it updated with the modified state value.

I also don't see it with this simpler example:

```js
const {useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const stop = Date.now() + 3000;
        while (Date.now() < stop) {
            // Wait (NEVER DO THIS IN REAL CODE)
        }
        console.log("Done waiting");
    }, []);
    return <div>x</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

When I run that, I see the `x` rendered by the component, then three seconds later I see the `console.log` that the wait has finished.

**But** if you aren't seeing what you describe, it would be just because the browser hasn't had a chance to actually draw the page before the `useEffect` is called, despite React's code trying to ensure that's the case. And since your code is a busy-wait, the main thread is tied up with that loop, and the browser can't update the page display.

But again, I don't see that with `useEffect` (you would with [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)).

Comment: Thank you for thorough answer! I see that in your code snippet `useEffect` works decently, but in a sandbox ([Link to Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-flower-2rw1ik?file=/src/App.js)), it waits for 3 seconds and only after draws the page. After some refreshing of a page (not local page rendered with the code, but whole Sandbox page), it works seldom as expected, but in most cases `useEffect` works as I've written in the question:(

Comment: @MichaelLearner - It's probably a CodeSandbox thing, there's a lot of moving parts there, the browser might not be able to fully update the UI. :-)

Answer (score -1):

What you see blank screen, it's correct according to code.

Because code code snippet you use is busy-wait script and makes your other javascript codes stopped and UI frozen.

And this is not good in terms of User Experience and performance.

```
    let start = new Date().getTime();
    let end = start;
    while (end < start + 3000) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
    }
```

So you can do it like the following:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

useEffect(() => {
    delay(3000).then(res => {
      setState(3);
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Actually, according to [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#timing-of-effects), React has at least made an effort to let the browser display the component before calling the `useEffect` callback.

Comment: Yes, React renders your body, then fires your `useEffect` hook after DOM is ready because your hook has an empty array dependency `[]`. But in this hook, a busy-wait (blocking) script is executed. While this looping, all other UIs to be rendered after this component will be stopped.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. With the OP's code, they should be seeing the page painted, because React supposedly commits and waits for a paint before calling `useEffect` (and thus before the busy-wait). I can't replicate what the OP describes, for me it always renders the page (then gets stuck on the busy-wait). Although fundamentally, it's the busy-wait that is the problem either way of course.